# How to parse plaintext data from a particular url with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, plaintext

I am using this code to pull data to my site from an external source, and am wondering how I would parse this using PHP.

```
include(app_path().'/Includes/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html("http://www.teamsideline.com/sites/parkfun/schedule/153461/Adult-Outdoor-Soccer-Mens-Competitive", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
$data = array();
foreach($html->find("tbody tr") as $tr){
$row = array();
foreach($tr->find("td") as $td){
    /* enter code here */
    $row[] = $td->plaintext;
}
$data[] = $row;
}
```

I am trying to extract the standings data in particular, and recreate the standings table on my page with the data from this site. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Ok and what is your exact problem? Is your code not working? Or du you have some other problems?

Comment: The code works, but how do I parse this data to display it on my site? The response I get from the site is very long and contains a lot of data that I do not need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the website doesn't allow file_get_html(). Atleast for me it's not working.

Anyway, you could use cUrl to get the html string and then parse that string using `str_get_html()`.

To display the table on your website, simply echo the found data like this:

```
$url = 'http://www.teamsideline.com/sites/parkfun/schedule/153461/Adult-Outdoor-Soccer-Mens-Competitive';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

$html = str_get_html($result);

$data = "";

$data .= "<table width='100%'>";

    foreach($html->find("tbody tr") as $tr){

        $data .= "<tr>";

        foreach($tr->find("td") as $td){

            $data .= "<td style='border: 1px black solid'>";
            $data .= $td->plaintext;
            $data .= "</td>";

        }

        $data .= "</tr>";

    }

$data .= "</table>";

echo $data;
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Is there any way I can take this further as to only pick out the data that I really need?

Comment: @hoolakoola No problem! Every situation is different with HTML parsing, so tell me what data you are specifically looking for and I might be able to help you ;-)

Comment: Sweeet! I am just trying to pull the standings data to put within my own table with the column names, since it doesn't seem like that part of the data that was retrieved.

Comment: @hoolakoola Aha. If you just want the standings data use `$table = $html->find("table", 1);` to get the second table on the page (which is the standings table), and then loop through using this `foreach($table->find("tr") as $tr) {`. To style the table, just add an id/class to the table like this `$data .= "<table id='standings-table'>";` and then style is in css using e.g. `#standings-table td { background-color: red }` to make the background color of the table cells red. Good luck!

Comment: Here's the full code that also includes the table title and column titles. I also added some CSS to make it look good. http://textuploader.com/d9toj

Comment: Ahhh this is amazing thank you so much! How would I remove the last column from the table?

Comment: @hoolakoola Use the foreach index. `foreach($tr->find("th") as $index => $th) {` and then in that foreach loop use `if($index === 9) { continue; }` to skip the 9th `th`. Same with the td's `foreach($tr->find("td") as $index => $td) {` and skip every 9th `td` with `if($index === 9) { continue; }`. Read the PHP docs to learn more about `continue`. Here's a link to the full script again, if you're confused http://textuploader.com/d9tq2. Oh, and could you upvote my comments if they were helpful?